# Como mostrar mais de um valor em um data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou usando uma base de dados com o seguinte dataframe

Código Venda    Data    ID Loja Produto Quantidade  Valor Unitário  Valor Final

```
0   1   2019-01-01  Iguatemi Esplanada  Sapato Estampa  1   358 358
1   1   2019-01-01  Iguatemi Esplanada  Camiseta    2   180 360
2   1   2019-01-01  Iguatemi Esplanada  Sapato Xadrez   1   368 368
3   2   2019-01-02  Norte Shopping  Relógio 3   200 600
4   2   2019-01-02  Norte Shopping  Chinelo Liso    1   71  71
```

Quero mostrar somente as linhas que possuam por exemplo o produto camiseta e e relógio ?
Como faço ? Só consigo colocar uma condiçao

meu codigo:

```
aa = vendas_df.loc[vendas_df['Produto'] == 'Sapato Estampa'  'Camiseta']

display(aa)
```

tentei usar parenteses, virgula, e ate &, alguem pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para realizar esse tipo de condição múltipla você precisa colocá-las entre parênteses separando-as usando o `&` ou `|`

```py
sapato = 'Sapato Estampa'
camiseta = 'Camiseta'
aa = vendas_df.loc[(vendas_df['Produto'] == sapato) & (vendas_df['Produto'] == camiseta)]
display(aa)
```

para mais exemplos veja a documentação oficial [documentação pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: Consegui e entendi a lógica, muito obrigado !!

Answer (score -1):

Olá experimenta usar o `isin`, tipo assim:

```
import pandas as pd

Table1 = {'Tamanho': ['P', 'P', 'M', 'G', 'G'], 'Tipo': ['Camisa', 'Calça', 'Jaqueta', 'Meia', 'Camisa'], 'Cor': ['Azul', 'Verde', 'Azul', 'Preto', 'Rosa']}

df= pd.DataFrame(Table1, columns=['Tamanho', 'Tipo', 'Cor'])

df_filter = df[df.Tipo.isin(['Camisa','Calça'])] #Esse é o filtro

print(df_filter)
```

Essa linha:

```py
df_filter = df[df.Tipo.isin(['Camisa','Calça'])]
```

É similar a essa:

```py
df_filter = df.loc[(df.Tipo == 'Camisa') | (df.Tipo == 'Calça')]
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Consegui e entendi a lógica, muito obrigado !!